# Why is $(3x+2)^n$ $\implies$ $(x-(-\frac{2}{3}))^n$ a valid modification?

Tags: factoring

Why can one write $(3x+2)^n$ as $(x-(-\frac{2}{3}))^n$?

Does it depend on the domain of $x$? Why does the $n$ exponent not cause a problem?

Comment: because it have the same root. not that they aren't equal...

Comment: The correct expression is $(3x+2)^n = 3^n\left(x - \left(-\frac{2}{3}\right)\right)^n$, you are missing the $3^n$ factor in front.

Comment: @Winther Well that makes more sense.

Comment: $$(3x+2)^n             =\left(3\cdot\left(x+\frac23\right)\right)^n             =3^n\cdot\left(x-\left(-\frac23\right)\right)^n.$$